# Vector Graphics: Stroking a Path

Tags: opengl, vector, graphics, path, stroke

In the figure below, I show the corners `A` and `B` of a vector path; I show the path drawn without a stroke applied, and the same path with a `6px` stroke. We can see that for straight lines, the stroked path maintains a constant `6px` distance against the contour; but when corner `A` is reached, the stroke's distance from the corner  can be slightly increased  in order to maintain proportions.

[image: Two vector paths, one with a stroke and one without.]

I cannot figure out the algorithm for calculating corner points of a stroke; I tried to calculate the central angle between the contours passing to and from the corner, but this distorts the shape.

Can anyone provide any useful resources or suggest an appropriate algorithm?

Comment: intersection of the stroke edges,

Comment: @ratchetfreak How did I not see that?! You fix my problems every time, ratchet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm simply extends the edge until it intersects with the next stroke edge.